# How can I optimize this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, html

A fellow stackoverflow member, @mrtsherman, helped me put together this little script that is supposed to generate a sentence based on the input of some form fields. I changed it up a bit to fit with my website, and was wondering if there's a way to optimize the code? (especially the 'case' part)

http://jsfiddle.net/pktMJ/3/

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"? You code seems to run just fine!

Comment: Know who is really good at reviewing code? [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: +1 for Chad. There, is where you can find your best answer =)

Comment: This code is basically too short to even try to optimize. You could use a dictionary, but there's really no need.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I pasted the wrong link. I've updated the one above.

Comment: "Know who is really good at reviewing code?" Hitler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/pktMJ/4/

Comment: +1 because this is *better*, but not ideal. The data dictionary that @DwB was going for is better if someone expands it to use two values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an optimization, but it removes the switch statement.

```
var verbMap =
{
    'Freshman':'studying',
    'Sophomore':'studying',
    'Junior':'studying',
    'Senior':'studying',
    'Masters Student':'studying',
    'Phd Candidate':'studying',
    'Masters Degree Holder':'having studied',
    'Phd Degree Holder':'having studied',
    'TA':'teaching',
    'Professor':'teaching',
    'Middle School Teacher':'teaching',
    'High School Teacher':'teaching'
};

document.getElementById('description').onchange = function()
    {

    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = this.value;

    var verb = verbMap[this.value];

    document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = verb;
};
```

Comment: My mistake, I've posted the wrong link. This is the one I was wondering about: http://jsfiddle.net/pktMJ/3/

Comment: The same technique applies.  instead of a switch statement you can use a (two in the case of the new fiddle link) map to determine the verb and question values.  I'll update my code above for the verbMap and leave the question map for the student.

Comment: Replace the verb value 'having studied' with 'who studied', replace the question 'What have you studied?' with 'What did you study?', and replace the question 'What are you teaching?' with 'What do you teach'.